# select box size after remove hide class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Good day sir, please check my script first ...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
 <label onclick="$('#asd').hide();" class="btn btn-info active ">
   <input type="radio" checked = 'checked' value="RM" id="posisi1" name="posisi"> RM
 </label>


<label  onclick="$('#asd').show();$('#asd').removeClass('hidden')" class="btn btn-info ">
     <input type="radio" value="Chief"  id="position2" name="posisi" > Chief
 </label>

<div class="form-group hidden" id = "asd">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pilih RM / Chief</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                                         
                      <option  value="120442130008">CHOIRUL ILYAS</option>
                                         
                      <option  value="1502017">CHOIRUL ILYAS</option>
                                         
                      <option  value="120442130009">Boby Kurniawan</option>
                    </select>
                     </div>
 </div>
```

When i run it at my pc (Local). the size of the selected box is small. But, when i run via 'Run Code Snippet' the size is normal. Is there any mistake ? .

[image: Here Is my Screenshot]

---

I think my problem when i use this

```
hidden{
       display:none;
    }
```

Comment: What obvious to me is that in your local pc select2 jquery plugin is included and here it is not.

Comment: Yes. I already use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you needed is something like this

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>





 <label onclick="$('#asd').hide();" class="btn btn-info active ">
   <input type="radio" checked = 'checked' value="RM" id="posisi1" name="posisi"> RM
 </label>


<label onclick="$('#asd').show(); $('#parent').select2();" class="btn btn-info ">
     <input type="radio" value="Chief"  id="position2" name="posisi" > Chief
 </label>

<div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id = "asd">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pilih RM / Chief</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select id="parent" class="form-control" name="parent">
                    <option value="none">None</option>

                      <option  value="120442130008">CHOIRUL ILYAS</option>

                      <option  value="1502017">CHOIRUL ILYAS</option>

                      <option  value="120442130009">Boby Kurniawan</option>
                    </select>
                     </div>
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle from your code - updated](https://jsfiddle.net/pmLyp1ms/1/)

Comment: i think my problem is when i use `.hidden{
       display:none;
    }
`

Comment: and please note that I also removed the class "select2" from your code.